# Matlab polyfit or cftool obtain coefficients with maximum accuracy

Tags: matlab, truncation, coefficients

I've fitted a 5th order polynomial through a small dataset and I want to extract the coefficients with maximum accuracy.

If I plot a polynomial using the coefficients that I can extract from matlab (using `coeff_6 = MyCoeffs(6)`) the coefficients are truncated, which completely ruins the fit.

I can plot the fit decently using:

```
p = polyfit(x1,y1,5)
p2 = polyval(p,x);
plot(x,p2);
```

However, I can't out yet how to extract the non-truncated coefficients. Could anyone help me please? By the way, I get the same problem when I use **cftool**.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "the coefficients are truncated"? Do you mean the number of decimal figures _shown_ by Matlab? If that's the case, try `format long` to get 15 decimals

Comment: Code indenting, readability

Comment: @LaurIvan if you're going to supplant someone else's perfectly good edit with superfluous additions you could at least get the product name correct. It's MATLAB.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem here is the p given by polyfit is literally the untruncated coefficients.  Its normally suppressed by matlab. You can see this by either opening the variable and clicking on it or using format long

Comment: The format long works. Thanks very much for your help!